# Rounded Images Show Corners On Transition then Immediately Become Rounded Again

Tags: html, css, twitter, carousel, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5.3 and whenever there is a transition in my carousel, the corners show, then become rounded again. Frankly, it’s in the title. That’s quite literally my problem.

What is shown right after transition:

[image: Image showing how the carousel edges are not rounded]

What it turns into (and is supposed to stay as):

[image: Images showing how the carousel edges become rounded right after the non-rounded edges are shown]

What more can I say? I’ve already tried to figure out if I’m missing any div tags. I’ve looked through the documentation. I have search StackOverflow. I’ve tried adding explicit, in-line styles (such as `style=“border-radius:2rem!important”)` to the images. I am desperate.

some custom `styles.css` (not all of the divs are shown in my other snippet):

```
<style>
i {
         padding-right:15px;
         }
         .iconwithoutpadding {
         padding-right:0px;
         padding-left:0px;
         }
         .dropup-tall-screens {
         position: absolute;
         bottom:0;
         padding-bottom:2vh;
         }
         .dropdown-small-screens{
         position:relative;
         display:none;
         }
         .small-screen-navbar {
         display: none;
         }
         /* Change the background color to #343a39 when the data-bs-theme is not "light" */
         html:not([data-bs-theme="light"]) .nav-item .dropdown-toggle:hover {
         background-color: #343a39;
         }
         .hrDarkNav {
         border-top:1px solid #656666;
         }
         /* Change the background color to #343a39 when the data-bs-theme is not "light" */
         html:not([data-bs-theme="light"]) .nav-item-only-hover:hover {
         background-color: #343a39;
         }
         .offcanvas-body {
         padding-top: 0;
         }
         @media screen and (max-height: 555px) {
         .dropdown-small-screens {
         display:block;
         }
         .offcanvas-body {
         margin-bottom: 1rem;
         }
         .dropup-tall-screens{
         display:none;
         }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 210px){
         .small-medium-screen-offcanvas{
         display: none;
         }
         .small-screen-navbar {
         display: block;
         }
         }
         /* Change the background color to a lighter color when the data-bs-theme is "light" */
         html[data-bs-theme="light"] .nav-item .dropdown-toggle:hover {
         background-color: #f8f9fa;
         color:#0d6efd;
         }
         /* Change the background color to a lighter color when the data-bs-theme is "light" */
         html[data-bs-theme="light"] .nav-item-only-hover:hover {
         background-color: #f8f9fa;
         color: #0d6efd;
         }
         #cookie-consent {
         background-color: #f8f9fa;
         border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
         padding: 1rem;
         text-align: center;
         }
         #cookie-consent p {
         margin: 0;
         font-size: 0.9rem;
         }
         #cookie-consent button {
         background-color: transparent;
         border: 0;
         color: #007bff;
         cursor: pointer;
         font-size: 0.9rem;
         outline: 0;
         }
         /* Make the cookie consent banner visible */
         #cookie-consent.visible {
         display: block;
         }
         /* Hide the cookie consent banner by default */
         #cookie-consent {
         display: none;
         }
         /* Hide a modal below a specific width */
         @media (max-width: 767px) {
         .modal-backdrop { 
         display: none !important;
         }
         #searchModal {
         display: none !important;
         }
         .modal-dialog {
         display: none !important;
         }
         }
         /* Hide a modal below a specific width */
         @media (max-width: 500px) {
         .modal-backdrop { 
         display: none !important;
         }
         #searchModal { 
         display: none !important;
         }
         .modal-dialog {
         display: none !important;
         }
         }
         /* Padding for boxed layout */
         @media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 767px) {
             .boxed-layout{
                 padding-left:20px;
                 padding-right:20px;
             }
         }
        /* Padding for boxed layout */
         @media (max-width: 500px){
             .boxed-layout{
                 padding-left:10px;
                 padding-right:10px;
             }
         }
        /* Padding for boxed layout */
         @media (min-width: 768px){
             .boxed-layout{
                 padding-left:20px;
                 padding-right:20px;
             }
         }
           .text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

`html`

```
<div class="container">
   <!-- Content -->
   <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
   <div id="carouselMaterialStyle" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="5000">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <div class="carousel-indicators">
         <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true"
            aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
         <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
         <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
      </div>
      <!-- Inner -->
      <div class="carousel-inner rounded-5 shadow-4-strong" data-bs-touch="true">
         <!-- Single item -->
         <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(25).webp" class="d-block w-100"
               alt="Sunset Over the City" />
            <div class="text">#1</div>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
               <h5>First slide label</h5>
               <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Single item -->
         <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(22).webp" class="d-block w-100"
               alt="Canyon at Nigh" />
            <div class="text">#2</div>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
               <h5>Second slide label</h5>
               <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!-- Single item -->
         <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(23).webp" class="d-block w-100"
               alt="Cliff Above a Stormy Sea" />
            <div class="text">#3</div>
            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
               <h5>Third slide label</h5>
               <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Controls -->
      <div class="carousel-control-bottom-right">
         <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
         </button>
         <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide="next" style="opacity:1">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Inner -->
   <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
</div>
```

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? And please pare your code down to the relevant parts and make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: create a reproducible example in Codepen, most likely your problem can be solved bt adding border radius too and overflow hidden to the parent of carousel items

Answer (score 0):

I have dropped all the CSS you have provided in your question and used only your HTML. I have removed the `radius-5` class that was in there.

I applied a simple `border-radius: 20px;` to the `.carousel-item` and used `overflow: hidden;` on that element as well. Seems to work fine.

```css
.carousel .carousel-item  {
  border-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content -->
  <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
  <div id="carouselMaterialStyle" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="5000">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Inner -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-touch="true">
      <!-- Single item -->
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(25).webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="Sunset Over the City" />
        <div class="text">#1</div>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>First slide label</h5>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Single item -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(22).webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="Canyon at Nigh" />
        <div class="text">#2</div>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Second slide label</h5>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Single item -->
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://mdbcdn.b-cdn.net/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(23).webp" class="d-block w-100" alt="Cliff Above a Stormy Sea" />
        <div class="text">#3</div>
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Third slide label</h5>
          <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
    <div class="carousel-control-bottom-right">
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide="prev">
         <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
         </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselMaterialStyle" data-bs-slide="next" style="opacity:1">
         <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
         <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
         </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Inner -->
  <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
</div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```